# Unexpected cancel signal and 503 response code

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

When working on my reactive REST endpoint using Spring Webflux, I realized that, if the returned `Publisher` does not complete in ~30 seconds, it is being canceled and a response code 503 is returned.

I haven't seen this behaviour documented anywhere.

An example REST controller:

```java
package myapp.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.time.Duration;

@RestController
public class TestAlationIndexingRestController {

    @RequestMapping(
        value = "/test",
        method = RequestMethod.GET
    )

    public Mono<String> test(HttpServletRequest request) {

        return Mono.delay(Duration.ofMinutes(2)).thenReturn("Late");
    }
}
```

Response: 503 with no response content

My question: How can I disable this behaviour, or at least increase the timeout?

Note: I have attempted to use the application property `server.connection-timeout: -1` or `server.connection-timeout: 15` without success - the request still timed out out after a little over 30 seconds.

---

I'm using the Spring Boot dependencies (version `2.1.6-RELEASE`):

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Interesting(+1) Can you show the pom. which version of springboot / webflux are u using. Also are u using tomcat or netty?

Comment: @pvpkiran I have added some dependency info to my question. I unfortunately cannot post the complete pom.

Comment: I am using 2.1.8.RELEASE and I cannot reproduce this issue

Comment: Did you solved it? I have the same issue

Comment: @CptDayDreamer I unfortunately did not. If you find the solution don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: Same issue for me. Any help please?

Comment: @Briston12 I wish I could help you. Just... don't use Spring in the future I guess.

Answer (score 1):

i've been stuck on such problem for several days. finally i find out the solution.

first add the async timeout configuration on application.yml

```
 spring:
  mvc:
    async:
      request-timeout: 60s
```

if the above configuration does not work. then try to add the following configuration in java code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public  void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(3600000);
    }
}
```

you may also get some clue from here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/kdoc-api/spring-framework/org.springframework.web.context.request.async/-timeout-deferred-result-processing-interceptor/index.html